# Start embedded react app with the external parameters

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a react app embedded in a webpage and the app should start with parameters it gets from the page. Now I pass the parameters on index.HTML file in a div but the problem is if the parameters are updated the app won't notice the changes.

index.HTML

```
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
      <meta name="description" content="Web site created using create-react-app" />
      <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
      <title>Sales flow</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div class="staringId" packageId="2" itemId="5" channelId="9"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

index.js

```
import './index.scss';
import App from './App'

const div = document.querySelector('.staringId')

    ReactDOM.render(
        <App domElement={div} />,
        div
    );
```

App.js

```
const App = ({ domElement }) => {
   const package = domElement.getAttribute("packageId")
   const item = domElement.getAttribute("itemId")
   const channel = domElement.getAttribute("channelId")

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    packageId: '',
    itemId: '',
    channelId: '',
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelData({
    packageId: package,
    itemId: item,
    channelId: channel,
  })
  }, [package, item, channel])
}
```

javascript file to embed the app

```
   <div class="staringId" packageId="2" itemId="5" channelId="9"</div>
    <script src="./dist/runtime-main.8d32315e.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/2.4c89be1e.chunk.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/main.a41deb26.chunk.js"></script>
```

My question is how I can pass some external parameters to the app and update(restart) the app after each update to the parameters.

Comment: Any reason why you want multiple `<App >` in your page? Maybe you can restructure the top level App component with multiple others components in it?

Comment: @HWSiew actually no reason, just updated the post. how do you mean to restructure the App comp?

Comment: how you update those attributes?? The component won't update unless there's state change, and domElement.getAttribute will not trigger any change in state

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial That is my question, how I can update those attributes. I know  getAttribute can't trigger changes in the state but I don't have any alternative either to read the parameters from dom and update the state by each change or try to pass the parameters by a function on the home page.

Comment: how did you embed into your webpage? you use Javascript and create a iframe right? can you share those codes?

Comment: add it to the question post thanks

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to have only one top-level  component in your HTML, and whatever parameters(props) you are trying to pass sit on the other components within the top-level . Following is the rough structure how it would look like.

index.html

```
<html>
 <body>
   <div id="app"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

index.js

```
import './index.scss';
import App from './App'

ReactDOM.render(
  <App  packageId="2" itemId="5" channelId="9" />, // you can choose to dynamically pass the value depends on what you get from page
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

App.js

```
const App = ( props ) => {
  // props.packageId and etc are available here 
  // you can then choose to render it with these props value
  return (
    <MyOtherComponent otherProps="ifany" />
  );

}

export default App;
```

Comment: @HWSien thanks for your answer. I already tried this solution but I couldn't pass the parameters from the host page to the react app. How would you embed the app and pass the params?

Comment: How is your parameters look like? a global variable or query string?

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by adding a vanilla JS DOM query in your index.js, then passing the element into your app.  Then your app will just use props as a standard function argument.

```js
// index.js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

// Find the app element
const widgetDivs = document.querySelectorAll('.mySpecialApp');

// Inject the app into each element found
widgetDivs.forEach(div => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App symbol={div.dataset.symbol}/>
      </React.StrictMode>,
        div
    );
});
```

```js
// App.js
const App = ({packageId, itemId, channelId}) => {

  const [data, setData] = useState({
    packageId: '',
    itemId: '',
    channelId: '',
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    setSelData({
    packageId: packageId, // set on the DOM element
    itemId: itemId,       // set on the DOM element
    channelId: channelId, // set on the DOM element
  })
  }, [package, item, channel])
}
```

And the html for your app would look like:

```html
<div class="mySpecialApp" packageId="1" itemId="2" channelId="3" />
```

This guide has more information and include bundling instructions if you want to be able to drop your app into some external app: https://tekinico.medium.com/build-a-react-embeddable-widget-c46b7f7999d8

Hope that helps 2 years later ;)